# Cant change text input with jQuery after user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table:
[image]

When the user choses a WorkCentre, a request is sent to get the default duration for that work centre and then this value is inserted into the appropriate field. But the user may wish to specify a different duration.
The automatic update of the duration works only if the user has not made a manual change. So if I was to enter 5 in the duration field of the last row it would get stuck at 5, even if I change the work centre.

Heres my code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select.form-control', function() {
    var WorkCentre = $(this).val();
    var i = $(this).attr('row-number');
    SetDuration(WorkCentre, i);
});

$(document).on('change', '.duration', function() {
    console.log('change');
    UpdateDates();
});

function SetDuration(WorkCentre, i) {
    $.get("/getDuration", {'WorkCentre' : WorkCentre}, function(data){
    var duration = data;
    $('input[name="Ops['+i+'][Duration]"]').val(duration);

    });
}
```

At the moment if the user selects a work centre, changes the duration from default to a custom value, but then decides they selected the wrong work centre and chooses a new one, the new default duration is not updated

You can see here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFxwYlH7df8
Once I manually change the duration, it gets stuck like that.

Comment: Add the code html to help!

Comment: share a fiddle link or create a snippet here

Comment: <input name="Ops[3][Duration]" type="text" row-number="3" value="10"> - for example

Comment: What's not working? Or do you want us to just write code for you?

Comment: Ive updated the question with a link to video

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the next line: (You reference is to select element, you should reference to selected item):

```
var i = $(this).attr('row-number');//No return data
```

Change by:

```
var i = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('row-number');//Return value of attribute
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/4pkdros9/1/

Comment: I can get the row number successfully. Like I said, initially the automatic update works fine but then after manually changing the field it doesn't

Comment: @ConnorBishop What is your function that change the duration ??

Comment: Try print values of `WorkCentre` and  `i` (when user change the option) , verify if you get return data!

Comment: Yes I do get return data, like I said initially the code works, only after a user input it stops working

Comment: @ConnorBishop  It's very strange, probably the input with the name not exist's, you can post your complete html to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120154/discussion-between-cmedina-and-connor-bishop).